# Fancybox 2.0.4 the fancybox function is removed from the jquery plugins

Tags: jquery, fancybox

First of all the issue is encountered when using the new version of fancybox (http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/).

I have an application which loads most of the pages using ajax. The scenario is the following:

1. My main page loads with jquery, jquery-ui and fancybox
2. Click on a link and fancybox opens with ajax content
3. When the ajax loads jquery-ui tabs are triggered to make some tabs (the opened window contains tabs), also some links in the ajax content are binded to open in fancybox
4. Click on a link in the ajax content and load another ajax content.
5. After the content is loaded window.$ is present but window.$.fancybox is undefined.

What could remove fancybox from the jquery plugins?
I have also attached an image with the console explaining the steps.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling for half an hour and not finding the problem I wrote the above post. Immediately after I wrote it I found out what was happening. I won't delete the question, as it may be of help to others.

One of my ajax requests was also loading a new jquery object which was resetting the old one, thus, the plugins. All of them.

Once the unnecessary request was removed everything works fine.